# HTML overflow:hidden doesn't format text correctly

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a website for an American Football team. They have these newsitems on their front page which they can manage through a CMS system. I have a problem with alligning the text inside those news items. Two of the news items look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the right newsitem text are displayed nicely. But the left cuts it off really bad. You can only see the top half of the text at the last sentence. I use **overflow: hidden;** to make sure the text doesn't make the div or newsitem bigger. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this through HTML and CSS or should I cut it off serverside with PHP?

Here's my code (HTML):

```
<div class="newsitem">
        <div class="titlemessagewrapper">
            <h2 class="titel" align="center"><?php echo $row['homepagetitel']; ?></h2>
            <div class="newsbericht">
                <?php echo $row['homepagebericht']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsfooter">
            <span class="footer_author"><a href=""><?php echo get_gebruikersnaam_by_id($row['poster_id']); ?></a></span> <span class="footer_comment"><a href="">Comments <span>todo</span></a></span>
            <a href="" class="footer_leesmeer">Lees meer</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.newsitem{
float: left;
height: 375px;
width: 296px;
margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;

}

.newsitem .titel{
color:#132055;
font-size:1.2em;
line-height:1.3em;
font-weight:bold;
margin:10px 5px 5px 5px;
padding:0 0 6px 0;
border-bottom:1px dashed #9c0001;
}

.titlemessagewrapper{
height: 335px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.newsitem .newsbericht{
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.newsitem .newsfooter{
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background-color: #132055;
margin: 0px auto;
font-size: 0.8em;
padding-top: 5px;
margin-top: 10px;
border: 1px solid #9c0001;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not rely on the user** to enter `<cut>` !

- User Input = error
- What if the user forgets to enter `<cut>`? Will your news item now look unprofessional?
- What would be the point of a user creating a news item to find that some of it was cut off?

If the div can only fit a fixed string length you should validate the max length of the news item Input body instead of relying on `<cut>`. This can be simply achieved using `maxlength` attribute.

```
<textarea id="userinput" maxlength="150">Enter your news</textarea>
```

If you do use `<cut>` you should also add in `overflow: hidden;` to ensure that the content is not unprofessionally displayed if no cut tag is present.

If you want to display the all text and keep the div the same fixed height

Replace

```
overflow: hidden;
```

with

```
overflow:auto;
```

(Scroll bar won't appear when content is smaller than the div)

Otherwise validate the length of the string / content in your div or remove the CSS height attribute to allow all the content appear with no scroll bars.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there thanks for your reply! I noticed the overflow:auto too, but It won't really look good so that was not an option. 

Because the user who fills the news items has different formatting options (bigger text, bold options, pictures etc) I would never have an idea when to cut off the text. Because one newsitem will have to cutoff after 100 characters while another should at 150 characters. right?

So my idea was: let the user create its text, then let it verify what he made by giving a preview of how the item will look. That way the user knows where to place the <cut> tag..

What you think?

Comment: You could create a nice Javascript or AJAX function that will allow the user to generate a preview. Create a replica news div beside the input box. When the user selects preview button the textarea input value should be displayed in the replica news div. There would be no need for the <cut> tag in this instance

Comment: Yes with AJAX it can look real nice! Thanks for the great idea, that's what I'm gonna do!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height attribute on the .titlemessagewrapper. Its this height attribute which is causing the cut off.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply :) The idea is that I want to cut the text off, because I want to have the newsitem a fixed height and width. I just don't want the browser to cut off the top 50% of the last sentence

Comment: Hello Rens, its best to do it server side - but it can be done with js, var newstring = oldstring.substring(0,500);

Answer (score 1):

If you want the boxes to remain the same height: Take the whole string, perform [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and save in a new variable and echo that.

Eg.

```
<?php
    $str = "abcdefghijkl";
    $new_strsubstr($str, 0, 8);  // abcdef
    // will return abcdefhi 
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, so you think there's no other way to do this than with PHP? Because depending on the titles I could never know how long the string length must be and so, I have no idea when to cut it off. I thought of letting the user, who creates these newsitems, put some kind of <cut> tag into it, in which case I would know... But I'd rather use HTML & CSS if possible

Comment: It can't be done with css or html unfortunately. You can use javascript too instead of php, but its better do it server side than client side (time to execute script, could cause page to appear to load modular. Can you not include your title in the strlen count?

Comment: Ok thanks! :) I do think that's going to be quite a puzzle then. I'll think I'll go with the <cut> tag so it's the user's responsibility and they can exactly create it how they want it. Too bad it can't be done through HTML and CSS only. Thanks man :)